# What is the professional way to deal with my manager's boss?

Tags: professionalism, management

When I joined this company. I was hired and put in direct report to my manager. After a while my manager's boss a.k.a the director starts to communicate with me. At first it was merely project progress. **Now he his asking me to give him a daily report on what am I doing regarding the project.** Is he allowed to do so? I feel the pressure and sometime feel to be treated like a little kid.

Furthermore he always gives bad ideas. Which leads me into wasting time researching things that are not going to be used. As a part of innovation team we need to present our project to the customers or any technical person whom comes to visit our plant. On up the coming Monday, the Chief HR Officer is dropping by for 2 hours for several issue. In his tight schedule, the director is planning to showcase the innovations. My big question would be what is the relevance of a Chief HR Officer to innovation program? There have been so many line visit has been misused for the innovation showcase. I feel like a clown every time, to set up everything and display the project to the person whom at the end would never even bother what ever we are doing.

How do I deal with this kind of person? Does it mean he is a big boss. I just need to follow the orders.

Comment: Sometimes you have to participate in the "dog and pony show" that many executives like to put on. It gives them and the project more visibility and even though it can be a political game, sometimes the illusion of innovation and progress is what will keep you and your team employed when executives are looking to cut budget.  Keep in mind that the director may know a lot more about what is going on at the organization than you do.

Comment: HR can affect raises, budget, resumes, employee retention, hiring, etc.

Comment: @maple_shaft in fact I was doing "dog and pony show" till the point he ordered me to do daily report. My style of work is complete 3 days of work in a day and chill. So I used to update him little by little, this is to keep him away from the project, as he will come and mess things up. But now I have to laterally come up with something just to type mail and show him what ever progress for today, Which I feel unprofessional at all.

Comment: @mkennedy Sorry I don't get your point.

Comment: You asked about the relevance of a Chief HR Officer to your innovation program. I listed some ways that HR could affect your program. If HR isn't happy with the program they could refuse to forward resumes, not approve new position or filling empty positions, etc.

Comment: @mkennedy I see. In that case he will be very unpleased as we are just going to waste his time. As the tentative program for him was a line walk to see some big issue going on the line. Not to attend this circus show. Furthermore we are not planing to hire new people and planned to ask fund from customer. He clearly stated in his mail, he is not well and does not plan for long line walk. My guess would be, we all be waiting for 2 hours on the floor, while he just going to skip the show.

Comment: @Sarenya Sounds like he is micromanaging you.  Maybe your style of work should change to accomodate?

Comment: @maple_shaft you have cleared all my doubts, indeed he is micromanaging. So I need to find away to escape from this  management style.

Comment: @Sarenya Well as the old saying goes, you can change your job or you can *change your job*. If it makes you terribly unhappy then it might be time for you to move on.

Comment: Re: @Sarenya's point "now I have to laterally come up with something just to type mail and show him what ever progress for today, Which I feel unprofessional at all." I would suggest to see if instead of emails the Boss would prefer a link to a weekly summary, or a spreadsheet on the server where you track your work on a weekly basis. Say you value his time and would rather provide information that is useful and at the right level of detail, rather than more info of lower quality. Daily email might not provide a big picture while weekly status would be enough (quality over quantity).

Comment: @Aymor will try to work it out with him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course your manager's boss can tell you what to do. It's obviously a bad idea to do that, he is hindering you in your job, and he is severely stepping on your manager's toes, so if I was your manager's bosses boss, I would tell him to stop it.

I'd say keep your manager informed about everything. If his boss tells you to do something, tell your manager about it. He can step in and tell you not to do it and fight it out with his boss. If you get conflicting orders, go to HR and ask them whose orders you are supposed to follow (it should be whatever your manager tells you). If you spend time doing work that his boss demands from you, obviously that takes up your time and other work won't get done.

Comment: I always kept my manager informed and execute my managers order. All the director needed was to ask my manager what is the progress done not site stepping like you said. Anyways, I have tendered my resignation letter. I just could not stand this political dilemma.